# Is it possible to create an Office 2003 VSTO add-in from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-office, vsto, add-in, office-2003

Is it possible to create an Office 2003 VSTO add-in from Visual Studio 2015? Its seem that VS2015 can only create VSTO add-in for Office 2010 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no,

In general Visual Studio Tools for the Office System templates (VSTO) in Visual Studio only support the latest two current versions of office for the time Visual Studio was released in.

Visual Studio 2010: Office 2007 ("Office 12"), Office 2010 ("Office 14"), Visual Studio 2012: Office 2010, Office 2013 ("Office 15"), Visual Studio 2013: Office 2010, Office 2013. Visual Studio 2015 is currently on Office 2013 and Office 2016.

I believe Office 2003 was only supported in a special SKU for Visual Studio 2003 and included later on in Visual Studio 2005 and 2008.

You can however start from scratch with a new blank project and add all the references you need to that project for Office and VSTO runtime (if you can still get hold of the VSTO runtime these days). It will be a manual process, and you'll miss the convenience of the VSTO project templates.

You also may question yourself if you really want to build an Office 2003 add-in today, as Microsoft ended its mainstream support April 14 2009.